# ObjectBox - DBException coming due to UID mismatching

Tags: android, database, migration, objectbox

I am using Objectbox as an ORM in my application and getting dbexception due to mismatching UID, when I added some extra properties in one of my entity. As I went through the documentation where it is mentioned that if we add or remove properties in your entities objectbox will take care of the changes. But it's not happening in my case. Please have a look at my log stash, entities and default.json once and let me know what could be the possible solution to resolve this issue.

ObjectBox version: v1.2.0

**Logs**

```
Caused by: io.objectbox.exception.DbException: Incoming entity ID 8:7509306813647547019 does not match existing UID 8172185837942255744
                                                                             at io.objectbox.BoxStore.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                             at io.objectbox.BoxStore.<init>(BoxStore.java:187)
                                                                             at io.objectbox.BoxStoreBuilder.build(BoxStoreBuilder.java:259)
                                                                             at com.letsdogether.dogether.dagger.module.ObjectModule.<init>(ObjectModule.java:34)
                                                                             at com.letsdogether.dogether.newDogetherHome.DogetherApplication.loadObjectsComponent(DogetherApplication.java:104)
                                                                             at com.letsdogether.dogether.newDogetherHome.DogetherApplication.onCreate(DogetherApplication.java:79)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1018)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4969)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1559) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5750) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

**Entities**

Previously my entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class BookingItem {

    private long id;
    @Id(assignable = true)
    private long priority;
    private String date;
    private String formattedAddress;
    private String orderId;
    private String type;
    private String title;
    private int seatCount;
    private String pricePerPerson;
    private String time;
    private String day;
    private String redirectUrl;
    private String status;
    private long experienceId;
    private String shareableUrl;
    private ToOne<Image> image;
    private ToOne<FeedElement> feedElementToOne;

}
```

and my default.json looks like this:

```
{
  "_note1": "KEEP THIS FILE! Check it into a version control system (VCS) like git.",
  "_note2": "ObjectBox manages crucial IDs for your object model. See docs for details.",
  "_note3": "If you have VCS merge conflicts, you must resolve them according to ObjectBox docs.",
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "1:4340630284304338974",
      "lastPropertyId": "8:4962045346664663063",
      "name": "BaseExperience",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:647607068638902600",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:2702040841419862055",
          "name": "actualId"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:3033280429430892352",
          "name": "avgRating"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:7218439493883955972",
          "name": "customerReviewsCount"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:80984715122814807",
          "name": "pricePerPerson"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:3883498391107289246",
          "name": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:8998466498535731699",
          "indexId": "1:1765637542740785127",
          "name": "videoId"
        },
        {
          "id": "8:4962045346664663063",
          "indexId": "2:2040540235098101863",
          "name": "feedToOneId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "2:7267925106594307597",
      "lastPropertyId": "17:4933883640820962465",
      "name": "BookingItem",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:2843152350771579539",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:3864807135625693365",
          "name": "priority"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:2811475968058126998",
          "name": "date"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:5994267266359962076",
          "name": "formattedAddress"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:8101006061974386478",
          "name": "orderId"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:5927620191588993112",
          "name": "type"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:6885331133485554648",
          "name": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "8:1499199287986398172",
          "name": "seatCount"
        },
        {
          "id": "9:2504021269483806060",
          "name": "pricePerPerson"
        },
        {
          "id": "10:7281235595111103399",
          "name": "time"
        },
        {
          "id": "11:6617722497399396474",
          "name": "day"
        },
        {
          "id": "12:2473985422221126897",
          "name": "redirectUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "13:2904830306792476987",
          "name": "status"
        },
        {
          "id": "14:2181195403266779204",
          "name": "experienceId"
        },
        {
          "id": "15:3018070061889416768",
          "name": "shareableUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "16:6444561946554419063",
          "indexId": "3:1705820361334358507",
          "name": "imageId"
        },
        {
          "id": "17:4933883640820962465",
          "indexId": "4:3744949801364672550",
          "name": "feedElementToOneId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "3:160108942376228999",
      "lastPropertyId": "6:8550232341754154098",
      "name": "Feed",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:1692860121377933562",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:8854384643059958161",
          "name": "type"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:7664556112391884481",
          "name": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:5817245497381540954",
          "name": "seeAll"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:2317329177962315800",
          "name": "feedType"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:8550232341754154098",
          "indexId": "5:680938987943440350",
          "name": "feedElementToOneId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "4:7537217652864317597",
      "lastPropertyId": "3:6112954104554042430",
      "name": "FeedElement",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:4926947771749822767",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:8131453946945993591",
          "name": "nextUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:6112954104554042430",
          "name": "feedElementType"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5:2348793681892920669",
      "lastPropertyId": "8:7488175383318173729",
      "name": "Image",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:638964174063060815",
          "name": "actualId"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:4967935003726444020",
          "name": "color"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:1353497332618194831",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:2887915135519113362",
          "name": "url"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:8827023004110736151",
          "name": "url1080"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:1795038216616196366",
          "name": "url160"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:5076768945024929823",
          "name": "url360"
        },
        {
          "id": "8:7488175383318173729",
          "indexId": "6:4968485658423571275",
          "name": "baseExperienceId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "6:2806463549017646468",
      "lastPropertyId": "7:1664725566577873631",
      "name": "Location",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:151476474888340297",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:6138069029925290631",
          "name": "city"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:8096792582877437443",
          "name": "formattedAddress"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:8477355478574191642",
          "name": "mapImgUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:5250680748074469313",
          "name": "redirectUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:5264044175718414745",
          "name": "lat"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:1664725566577873631",
          "name": "lng"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "7:1386266048121100599",
      "lastPropertyId": "19:3626459003273476368",
      "name": "User",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:7194535953200583315",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:5880155672016170214",
          "name": "age"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:7058496909689094561",
          "name": "bio"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:7069552521054985458",
          "name": "dob"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:2017478464009051869",
          "name": "education"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:7411668424835907052",
          "name": "email"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:3598420919065748818",
          "name": "fullName"
        },
        {
          "id": "8:55256390599336845",
          "name": "gender"
        },
        {
          "id": "10:4287083418016851024",
          "name": "numberVerified"
        },
        {
          "id": "11:7486368292287445046",
          "name": "phoneNumber"
        },
        {
          "id": "12:332314590071314536",
          "name": "shareableUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "13:3581159011829058253",
          "name": "showTutorial"
        },
        {
          "id": "14:45244862441869123",
          "name": "username"
        },
        {
          "id": "15:80719230754500568",
          "name": "verified"
        },
        {
          "id": "16:8347557177943880481",
          "name": "work"
        },
        {
          "id": "17:8060185784410064574",
          "indexId": "7:3086777593508744479",
          "name": "locationRelationId"
        },
        {
          "id": "18:7093446540087310685",
          "indexId": "8:4392926741093129871",
          "name": "profilePictureRelationId"
        },
        {
          "id": "19:3626459003273476368",
          "name": "host"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "8:8172185837942255744",
      "lastPropertyId": "4:2905712751785391104",
      "name": "Video",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:4230636119749821279",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:7059360054054181511",
          "name": "nightMode"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:7865268851517989166",
          "name": "thumbnailUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:2905712751785391104",
          "name": "url"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  "lastEntityId": "8:8172185837942255744",
  "lastIndexId": "8:4392926741093129871",
  "lastRelationId": "0:0",
  "lastSequenceId": "0:0",
  "modelVersion": 4,
  "modelVersionParserMinimum": 4,
  "retiredEntityUids": [],
  "retiredIndexUids": [],
  "retiredPropertyUids": [
    5678282376830830494
  ],
  "retiredRelationUids": [],
  "version": 1
}
```

Now after adding two new properties to my entity:

```
@Entity
public class BookingItem {

    //region Variables

    private long id;
    @Id(assignable = true)
    private long priority;
    private String date;
    private String formattedAddress;
    private String orderId;
    private String type;
    private String title;
    private int seatCount;
    private String pricePerPerson;
    private String totalTax; // 1st new propery
    private String totalAmount; // 2nd new property
    private String time;
    private String day;
    private String redirectUrl;
    private String status;
    private long experienceId;
    private String shareableUrl;

    private ToOne<Image> image;
    private ToOne<FeedElement> feedElementToOne;

    //endregion
}
```

and my default.json file:

```
{
  "_note1": "KEEP THIS FILE! Check it into a version control system (VCS) like git.",
  "_note2": "ObjectBox manages crucial IDs for your object model. See docs for details.",
  "_note3": "If you have VCS merge conflicts, you must resolve them according to ObjectBox docs.",
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "1:797065206246794980",
      "lastPropertyId": "6:5238604438383493820",
      "name": "Feed",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:4778143127430396941",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:2758756424257447876",
          "name": "type"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:8593664445454711775",
          "name": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:3260484052954017714",
          "name": "seeAll"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:5439051893044673734",
          "name": "feedType"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:5238604438383493820",
          "indexId": "1:9094671316112178979",
          "name": "feedElementToOneId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "2:6365001579184770311",
      "lastPropertyId": "8:4101477603790778141",
      "name": "BaseExperience",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:22769140630409817",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:9018492547283474382",
          "name": "actualId"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:7038610176041110296",
          "name": "avgRating"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:6685630808795149304",
          "name": "customerReviewsCount"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:700371560430014226",
          "name": "pricePerPerson"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:5016151397612468696",
          "name": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:1936717642548225179",
          "indexId": "2:1430584179264421000",
          "name": "videoId"
        },
        {
          "id": "8:4101477603790778141",
          "indexId": "3:2605016395080192788",
          "name": "feedToOneId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "3:6907123400855664498",
      "lastPropertyId": "7:2458659011456972963",
      "name": "Location",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:7686305118064424277",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:2382662573706119095",
          "name": "city"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:6622007474920998885",
          "name": "formattedAddress"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:4372387463973357662",
          "name": "mapImgUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:4242635850865049170",
          "name": "redirectUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:6362649356171979743",
          "name": "lat"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:2458659011456972963",
          "name": "lng"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "4:1653889744595737127",
      "lastPropertyId": "4:1222058476100793989",
      "name": "Video",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:8884142329290866772",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:9063641434858436120",
          "name": "nightMode"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:6750530027777030938",
          "name": "thumbnailUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:1222058476100793989",
          "name": "url"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5:2328616238996484251",
      "lastPropertyId": "18:8914368039716260545",
      "name": "User",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:8699946482619760537",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:4839102804066560980",
          "name": "age"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:4125992685805831147",
          "name": "bio"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:1279509102068824378",
          "name": "dob"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:2555427309043212840",
          "name": "education"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:5872521230199756193",
          "name": "email"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:3289121993356321",
          "name": "fullName"
        },
        {
          "id": "8:568408267657413444",
          "name": "gender"
        },
        {
          "id": "9:5476542265369423309",
          "name": "host"
        },
        {
          "id": "10:7787973054527294793",
          "name": "numberVerified"
        },
        {
          "id": "11:7196291790521558535",
          "name": "phoneNumber"
        },
        {
          "id": "12:1859664059288662356",
          "name": "shareableUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "13:4056506903853763516",
          "name": "showTutorial"
        },
        {
          "id": "14:5747800400884843324",
          "name": "username"
        },
        {
          "id": "15:3715522420100243828",
          "name": "verified"
        },
        {
          "id": "16:3996139181248738872",
          "name": "work"
        },
        {
          "id": "17:3912614163504861034",
          "indexId": "4:724013235730952653",
          "name": "locationRelationId"
        },
        {
          "id": "18:8914368039716260545",
          "indexId": "5:9128231055610190580",
          "name": "profilePictureRelationId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "6:162879391314678826",
      "lastPropertyId": "19:5998558359424914894",
      "name": "BookingItem",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:7685664473128076565",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:4691963051617887607",
          "name": "priority"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:4751608989851978419",
          "name": "date"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:4298668252649681543",
          "name": "formattedAddress"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:3557896982175720249",
          "name": "orderId"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:5444396912371992185",
          "name": "type"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:6350566628717896888",
          "name": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "8:5815948248926709539",
          "name": "seatCount"
        },
        {
          "id": "9:1347517584208111506",
          "name": "pricePerPerson"
        },
        {
          "id": "10:161182016726729049",
          "name": "totalTax"
        },
        {
          "id": "11:2603677420345643342",
          "name": "totalAmount"
        },
        {
          "id": "12:6964519603978301018",
          "name": "time"
        },
        {
          "id": "13:6563743671015329186",
          "name": "day"
        },
        {
          "id": "14:5252213579952934956",
          "name": "redirectUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "15:213202584538548112",
          "name": "status"
        },
        {
          "id": "16:2664627056996276806",
          "name": "experienceId"
        },
        {
          "id": "17:5051545379861430992",
          "name": "shareableUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "18:4513563003576451503",
          "indexId": "6:4794120774209056940",
          "name": "imageId"
        },
        {
          "id": "19:5998558359424914894",
          "indexId": "7:2963448740658161805",
          "name": "feedElementToOneId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "7:6072605387056962258",
      "lastPropertyId": "8:620926858576597520",
      "name": "Image",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:4722495423798219248",
          "name": "actualId"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:5785809790036589091",
          "name": "color"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:898405045397421733",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "4:5442888368829266995",
          "name": "url"
        },
        {
          "id": "5:3501485434468197765",
          "name": "url1080"
        },
        {
          "id": "6:1316954607651171513",
          "name": "url160"
        },
        {
          "id": "7:2942445530687114413",
          "name": "url360"
        },
        {
          "id": "8:620926858576597520",
          "indexId": "8:7864085141767381960",
          "name": "baseExperienceId"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "id": "8:7509306813647547019",
      "lastPropertyId": "3:6958687385472305063",
      "name": "FeedElement",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:3560464698535580090",
          "name": "id"
        },
        {
          "id": "2:7436822921002379968",
          "name": "nextUrl"
        },
        {
          "id": "3:6958687385472305063",
          "name": "feedElementType"
        }
      ],
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  "lastEntityId": "8:7509306813647547019",
  "lastIndexId": "8:7864085141767381960",
  "lastRelationId": "0:0",
  "lastSequenceId": "0:0",
  "modelVersion": 4,
  "modelVersionParserMinimum": 4,
  "retiredEntityUids": [],
  "retiredIndexUids": [],
  "retiredPropertyUids": [],
  "retiredRelationUids": [],
  "version": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution as stated in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/271#issuecomment-346304217):

The IDs of the two versions in your project are totally off: https://www.diffchecker.com/PF3UlSM7

Please revert to the old "default.json" file and rebuild. There should only be little differences in this file on updates.

Answer (score 3):

In case you deleted the app/objectbox-models/default.json and uninstalled the app from your android device but the issue still prevails check your manifest file for `android:allowBackup="true"` and change it to false. Then repeat the steps again.

This cost me an hour of my life, hope it helps.

Source: [The Nuke Option](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/meta-model-ids-and-uids)

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You probably changed your object structure after it created once.

**The easiest option to solve it:**
Like you said, If it possible you need to remove the `default.json` file (that build automatically while you build your project). and in the next build it will create again.

I recommend you to read about [Resolving Meta Model Conflicts](http://objectbox.io/documentation/meta-model-ids-uids/) in objectbox documentation.

Comment: Thank you, buddy. I really appreciate your effort in helping and trying to resolve my issue. Apologies for replying so late.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved and the issue actually is that I deleted my old default.json file by mistake which i didn't have to, which eventually led to regenerate the ids of all the entities and caused me a mismatching UID exception. Thanks to Markus Junginger.